# Tipo de relações 1:1

Tags: mysql

Porque quando ia refazer as relações da minha tabela 1:1 Aparecem-me dois tipos no WorkBench 
1:1 ---------
1.1_***_*__** (Com o traço no meio mas a linha recta)

Qual a diferença de um para o outro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A diferença de tracejados tem a haver com o uso de chaves primárias de uma tabela para outra.
No caso de usares `---` vais buscar a chave primária da tabela com a qual estás a fazer a relação, ficando a mesma como chave secundária. No caso do `___`, importas chave primária de uma tabela para a outra, mas agora ficando como chave primária e não como secundária.

Penso que a seguinte imagem ilustra bem o que quero dizer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]